# Search and write lines of multiple strings in python?

Tags: python

```
def info(): #Here you can write your password and username.
 Username = raw_input ("Username: ")
 Password = raw_input ("Password: ")
 print("")
 for line in open('/home/hello/Usernames.txt'):
  if Username == Username in line: #Checks if username is available.
   print ("Username is already taken!\n")
   info()
  else: 
   User = open("/home/hello/Usernames.txt", "w") #Registers username.
   User.write(Username)
   Psw = open("/home/hello/Passwords.txt", "w") #Registers password.
   Psw.write(Password)
   print ("You have succsesfully registered!") #If you managed to register.
   break 

info()
```

This is an account registerer that can register both username and password. But I need help with something... How can I make it check multiple lines of strings in a file, and how can I make the program write a new line of string in the text files when I register without replacing the old string?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file for appending (`'a'`) mode instead of writing (`'w'`) which truncate the file.

Comment: I tried your tip, it only goes one line under the first username registered, and when I register a third username and a fourth username. Then it just write on the same line as username two. Here's what happening: I have registered username number two named "username2"  then I register a third username named "username3" When the program write "username3" to the text file then it's not going a line down. the result becomes "username2username3"

Comment: You need to write the newlines into the file yourself: `User.write(Username+"\n")`